# HP Laptop Battery Drains to almost 0% Immediately

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a HP Envy 15" laptop that I use for my school work. Recently, I have a serious draining problem with the laptop's battery. When it is discharged, and the battery level has decreased to about 75% to 80% (68% if I'm lucky), my laptop will immediately go into hibernation mode. I cannot switch the computer back on unless I connect it to my charger.

Once I manage to power back on my computer, the battery indicator will show that the battery is usually at 0%.

I've run the HP Battery Check utility, and it reported that my battery is working fine, which obviously, is not.

This problem is quite annoying as I may not have access to my charger all the time. Is this a hardware or a software problem please? Would a factory reset of my laptop do any good?

Comment: Your battery is no longer holding a charge. Buy a new battery. That's all there is to it. A factory reset of your laptop won't solve your issue.

Comment: Batteries wear out, they often show it by not holding nearly as much charge as they should.  I've watched a UPS go 100%, 80%, 60%, 40%, 20%, off over about 5 seconds.  I replaced the batteries and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks n8te and Loren Pechtel for your advice. Greatly appreciated :)